# Есть ли споcобы посылать автоматические запросы к Google?

Tags: seo, google-search

Не подскажите, есть ли способ(ы) делать автоматические запросы к google для мониторинга позиций web-сайтов? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: seo горите в аду =)

Answer (score 3):

Если я не ошибаюсь все парсят выдачу гугла. По крайней мере я когда то спокойно распарсил необходимую мне выдачу без проблем. Просто не наглейте и делайте вменяемые промежутки между запросами.

Answer (score 0):

Если не изменяет память, то Google Alert вам в помощь.

Comment: К сожаленю не пойдет из-за малой эффективности и и неудобного формата оповещений. Я спрашивал про аналог Yandex XML или возможность (и характеристики, по которым не банят) proxy - запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Сам сервис у Гугла есть, но он очень дорогой и им никто не пользуется. Вам нужны сервисы которые напрямую парсят и выдают ответ в виде xml фида. Например https://xmlriver.com/apidoc/ (ясное дело что платно).
Напомню что позиции по запросам есть в Гугл консоли бесплатно
https://search.google.com/search-console?hl=ru